# Approaching a large regex issue

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so I have this problem where I need to create a class that has a Constructor to take in a string, a method called add which takes a String-Object pair where the name is the placeholder name and a method called render which replaces the placeholders in the template with the pairs given in add.

All of these need to be able to complete the following tests with no problems.

```
@Test
    public void testString() {
        View view = new View("Hi, my name is {name}!");
        view.add("name", "Josh");
        Assert.assertEquals("Hi, my name is Josh!", view.render());
    }

    @Test
    public void testList() {
        View view = new View("<table>{rows}</table>");
        view.add("rows", Arrays.asList("<tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr>", "<tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr>"));
        Assert.assertEquals("<table><tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr><tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr></table>", view.render());
    }

    @Test
    public void testView() {
        View view = new View("<table>{rows}</table>");

        View row1 = new View("<tr><td>{firstName}</td><td>{lastName}</td></tr>");
        row1.add("firstName", "Louis");
        row1.add("lastName", "Armstrong");
        View row2 = new View("<tr><td>{firstName}</td><td>{lastName}</td></tr>");
        row2.add("firstName", "Benny");
        row2.add("lastName", "Goodman");

        view.add("rows", Arrays.asList(row1, row2));
        Assert.assertEquals("<table><tr><td>Louis</td><td>Armstrong</td></tr><tr><td>Benny</td><td>Goodman</td></tr></table>", view.render());
    }
```

The only problem is that I have no idea how to go about this at all. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: You could try using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since this appears to be [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), I won't provide a full solution, but as asked I'll provide some general considerations/tips.

---

Taking the first test case as an example:

- capture the argument/parameter to the `View` constructor as a member variable. We will call that member variable `text`.
- capture each key-value relationship provided to `add`. Generally, this will be accomplished with a [Mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) data structure. If that option isn't available to you, then you could always modify `text` directly with each call to `add`.
- perform the replacement of `render`. That is easily accomplished by the [replace method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). If `text` was modified in `add` then just return it.

So all together without wrapping those implementation details into a `View` class, it would look something like

```
@Test
public void testString() {
    String text = "Hi, my name is {name}!";

    final Map<String, String> placeHolderToReplacement = new HashMap<>();
    placeHolderToReplacement.put("name", "Josh");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : placeHolderToReplacement.entrySet()) {

      text = text.replace("{"+entry.getKey()+"}", entry.getValue());

    }

    Assert.assertEquals("Hi, my name is Josh!", text); 
}
```

I think that should give you enough of a starting point to solve the problem.

Now, the post explicitly states `String-Object pair`. Does it have to be the exact same `add` method that takes the Collection of `View` objects and the `String`? You'll have to make the consideration of whether to provide an `overloaded` method vs a single method is acceptable. If it has to be the same method, then you'll need to perform the type checks yourself.

Comment: I just checked the existence of the homework tag. :)

Comment: Some of the stackexchange sites have one ;). It would become saturated on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class View {
    private String v;
    public View(String v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public void add(String key, String value) {
        v = v.replaceAll("{" + key + "}", value);
    }

    public String render() {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to recommend this for deletion, but it really should have some explanation around it -- for example, you could explain how it helps the OP with their problem.

Comment: Since the first parameter to `replaceAll` is regex, you need to escape the special characters `{` and `}` or you'll get an error.